# Order by for relationship in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a tables:

1. Analyses, columns(`id, name, game_id(FK)`);
2. Games, columns(`id, name, round_id(FK)`);
3. Round, columns(`id, round`);

I need get all records of Analyses order by (`round_id`).

I try `Analyses::orderBy('round_id')->get()`, but not work;

Comment: what is the thrown error , what is the output and what is the wanted result?

Comment: also you dont have round_id in Analyses table! , do you mean that you want the games for each analyses ordered by round_id?

Comment: Then you can simply join analysis and game table then order by `round_id`

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you dont have that column in your analyses table

to do the orderby you have to add this to your relation (assuming they are correctly done)

**Analyses model**

```
public function games()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class)->orderBy('round_id'); //see? we can add orderBy to the relation
}
```

**Games model**

```
public function rounds()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Round::class); // i dont know if its manytomany for eal, im just trying to explain 
}
```

Now you can get all the Analyses with the games and round using eagerloading like this

```
$test = Analyses::with('games.round')->get();
```

you can chain another orderby for Analyses like this for exemple

```
$test = Analyses::with('games.round')->orderby('game_id')->get();
```

in the above exemple , you will have Analyses ordered by game_id and the games inside each Analyse will be orderedby round_id

I hope this is what you want to do

Comment: yes, the relationships exists in model, I tried what you said but too does not work, return error that column not exist.

Comment: show us what you did exactly? what did you change! , paste your relations code in the answer please it would be easier to help

Answer (score 0):

```
Set the following relationships in to the respective model as given below
```

Analyses model

Round Model

```
public function games()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('Game','game_id','id'); 
 }
```

Game Model

```
public function analyses()
 {
   return $this->hasMany('Analyses','round_id','id'); 
 }
```

Your Query Should be like This

```
    $round_game_wise_analyses= Round::with(['game'=>function($query){
                                $query->select()
                                ->with(['analyses'=>function($query){
                                          $query->select(); 
                                        }]);
                                }])->orderBy('id','asc')->get();
```